# Run Shell Script before build of Android Project

Tags: android, bash, shell, cordova, phonegap-build

I am working on PhoneGap App using Eclipse IDE with Android Development Toolkit.

I am not familiar with Shell Scripting.  I got some requirements like - to change the directory structure while export as an APK.

[image]

"CORE/100000/default" should be discarded from the directory structure in the APK.

How to do this? Is there any way to do that? Please help me. Any suggestion.

Thank You

Comment: Why you have this directory structure?, If you create the project successfully, you should to have a www directory.

Comment: There is an answer. Please ask at the [official Phonegap forum](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi).

Comment: I need this because we are using Resource Mapper in Apache. In HTML we donit include "CORE/100000/default" for any js,css resource. It is handled by the resource mapper. In PhoneGap App we don't have Apache. So to achieve this resource mapping in phone gap I am looking for some alternative